# Cant Connect Using Mssql Pconnect

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, php-mssql

Code of config

```
Line 5 =   `if (!($link=mssql_pconnect("zzzzz\xxxx","sa","sssssss")))`
```

error is

> Warning: mssql_pconnect() [function.mssql-pconnect]: Unable to connect to server: zzzzz\xxxx in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\config\config.php on line 5

my friend told that is last update is 1.7.3

but i'm using latest xampp,
how to convert those code for the latest php?

Comment: The DNS name represented here by `zzzzz` and the instance name by `xxxx`? Is TCP port 1433 open on the firewall? Is it actually a named instance or the default instance? If the latter, is SQL Browser service started and the instance TCP port also open? Does the instance allow remote connections?

Comment: zzzzz is my servername, xxxx is my instance name, tcp port 1433 is open. i can connect using sql server management, but my code cant connect to my php file.

Comment: Connecting with `servername\instancename` requires that the SQL Browser Service is running on the target server and that udp/1434 is not blocked by a firewall. Since you already know that the instance is running on port 1433 try using `servername:1433` in your connection string instead, which then avoids the need to communicate with the SQL Browser Service.

Comment: i think its already on port 1433

Comment: not fixed. i already open the tcp and the udp. but same error